# Can anyone help translate this signature / red seal

Tags: translation, seal

[image][image]Ive had this painting/print for years, i inherited it from my Uncle.
Ive always wanted to know what the red seal means and the translation of the text.

I would love to find out more about the artist

Answer (score 3):

The text in the picture read from right to left (Chinese format), my answer below read from left to right in the English format

江邨烟云 - River village mist and cloud

[戊寅](https://zh-yue.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%88%8A%E5%AF%85) - The year (most likely 1938 or 1998)

秋 - Autumn

紹荋 - /Shào ér/ (name of the artist on the seal)

*[荋](https://www.zdic.net/hant/%E8%8D%8B) - grassy (also a grass plant's name)*

**Edit:**

dROOOze wrote: *紹英 rather than 紹荋*

英 looks like this [image]

荋 looks like this [image]

Seems like dROOOze is right and 英 is a much more common name (for male or female)

The author's name is 紹英 - /Shào yīng/

Comment: 紹英 rather than 紹荋

Comment: That is really helpful, Thankyou very much its really appreciated.